# How to logout user for every new version of a website from the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I hope you are doing well!

We have a website that is in construction at the moment but we found something that would need fixing which is, if we change something in the login process (returns or something) and use that data we added in our website, any user already logged in would have the website crashed for them unless they logout and login again.

We store if the user is logged in by saving data as well as the JWT token in redux (we obviously encrypted them).

How can we achieve the following:

For every new version we deploy, logout all currently logged in users so they are forced to login again next time they enter the website?

I searched a bit and found solution for nodeJS and others but none for React, especially since we are using rest APIs (as well as graphQL) so logging our the user cannot be from the backend.

Comment: Are you really going to change the login process a lot? Might be one of those things that you might spend tons of hours on fixing for once in a blue moon. You can add a check in page loads for verison numbers and redirect, but you have to think about if a user is in a multiple step form or something and you break that flow how is that experience. Can't you make the code that uses that info not break when the data is not there?

Comment: @epascarello These changes are still in the beginning stages, so sometimes I would require different values to be returned to me from the backend on login and would use these values for some processes in the application (think sending a user's company information when they are creating a role and such) so in those moments we sometimes encounter this thing more than usual. However, it has been asked from us to do it this way so hence why I'm having to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not a good practice at all, but if it needs to be done I would suggest a couple of options. Neither of them is pure React, but anyway this logic should be done on the server because if you do it only in redux it can lead to broken access control:

1. Include the version number in the JWT token. Then in the BE when doing the JWT validation you should check the version number as well.
2. When you make new deployment invalidate/delete the existing JWT tokens. This will force the users to log in next time but if the FE and BE have independent deployments it might be tough to do automatically

Comment: Would it be better practice if say, I save the version number and once I see that it has changed, we go through a re-login process for the user and take them back to where they were?